# I am getting an error while uploading image URL to firebase database from the firebase storage

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, imageurl

I got this in firebase:
[image: I got this in firebase]

```
private fun uploadToFireBase(imageUri: Uri) {
    binding.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    val fileRef : StorageReference = storageReference.child("${System.currentTimeMillis()}.${getFileExtension(imageUri)}")
    fileRef.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener {


        fileRef.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
            binding.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE

            val hackathonModel = HackathonModel(binding.HackTitleET.text.toString() , binding.HackUrlET.text.toString() ,
                binding.HackLocationET.text.toString(), imageUri.toString()
            )

            val hackathonModelId : String? = root.push().key
            root.child("HackathonsUsers").child(firebaseAuth.currentUser!!.uid).child(hackathonModelId.toString()).setValue(hackathonModel)
            root.child("AllHackathons").child(hackathonModelId.toString()).setValue(hackathonModel)


            Toast.makeText(this, "Hackathon Uploaded Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val intent = Intent(this , MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }

    }.addOnProgressListener {
        binding.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }.addOnFailureListener{
        binding.progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        binding.postHackBT.visibility= View.VISIBLE
        Toast.makeText(this, "Uploading Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

private fun getFileExtension(imageUri: Uri): String? {
    val cr : ContentResolver = contentResolver
    val mime : MimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton()
    return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cr.getType(imageUri))
}
```

how to fix this error and get a link in correct form not in this form (`content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A428613`)?

Comment: No pictures please. Post all text as text.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating your model with:

```
val hackathonModel = HackathonModel(binding.HackTitleET.text.toString() , binding.HackUrlET.text.toString() ,
    binding.HackLocationET.text.toString(), imageUri.toString()
)
```

That last argument is `imageUri.toString()`, which is the path to the image on your local Android device, and **not** the download URL that you told Firebase to generate for you.

To get the latter:

```
fileRef.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { task ->
    binding.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE

    if (task.isSuccessful) {
        val downloadUri = task.result

        val hackathonModel = HackathonModel(binding.HackTitleET.text.toString() , binding.HackUrlET.text.toString() ,
            binding.HackLocationET.text.toString(), downloadUri.toString()
        )
        ...
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [getting the download URL after uploading a file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#get_a_download_url).